# Use of '@' '.' and 'public operator/keywords in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I got into a weird SQL query-patch which looks for `@` `.` and `public` keywords.  I was wondering what is the purpose of these operators/keywords?

I suspect that it might be looking for SQL injection or some weird buffer overflow 
but I can't seem to understand why it looks for those characters, etc, and I can't find much information about those keywords.

If anyone could enlighten my eyes, it will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking here - `public` as in `create public synonym` `@` as in dblinks and `.` as in schema qualifier? Perhaps post some of the SQL?

Comment: Hi, it is not exactly a query but an external function (written in c, no src though) which looks for them and throws an exception if anything is found. The function basically checks whether or not you have the correct privileges to access an object and how (select, update , etc). I do not know what is the purpose of those chars, and I couldn't find much information about the dot and the @ sign, I was wondering if you could enlighten me with usage of these operators.

Answer (score 3):

This diagram is from the Oracle Docs [Syntax for Schema Objects and Parts in SQL Statements](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51132) page:

[image: general syntax for referring to an object or a part]

It shows the general use of the period character (`.`) for [qualification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) and the `@` symbol for referencing dblinks.

The `@` symbol is also used [when creating dblinks](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51138).

Given that the `public` keyword [is also used](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/ds_admin008.htm#ADMIN12188) for creating them, I think it is likely that your external function is doing something with dblinks!